# "What else it could be?" vs. "What else could it be?" - which is correct?

Tags: questions-v-relatives

- What else it could be?
- What else could it be?

I saw both of these sentences have been used in English. Are they both correct? If so, what is the sentence structure of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word order in a question requires that the verb precedes the subject.

Here '**it**' is the subject, '**could**' is the verb, so the proper way to form the question would be to put '*could*' before '*it*':

> What else **could** it be?